How many perfect squares can be formed by using one hundred 1s, one hundred 2s, and one hundred 0s?

How many perfect squares can be formed by using one hundred 1s, one hundred 2s, and one hundred 0s?

Honestly, I am almost clueless in this question.
I notice that if we make a number such as $x=111...1222...2000...0$, there will be an even number of zeros in the end. Also the number is congruent $0\mod9$.
Question had been sourced from a regional exam in Assam, India.

Please edit to include your efforts.  A natural start might be to solve the same problem with a smaller number than $100$  of each.  Also, for context:  If this is from a contest, please supply a link or reference to that context.

Also...why does your example use $0's$?  The problem statement only refers to the digits ${1,2,3}$.

One hundred $1$'s, one hundred $2$'s and one hundred $3$'s make a number $\equiv 6 \mod 9$.  Can that be a square?

@Robert Israel Excellent remark. Here is a Stack Exchange reference for those who haven't met this property.

@RobertIsrael How do we find that congruency?

$100 \cdot 1 + 100 \cdot 2 + 100 \cdot 3 \equiv  100 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3) \equiv 6 \mod 9$.

I just replaced $100$ by $2$. I found following squares, only containing $0$, $1$ and $2$: $0$, $1$, $100$, $121$, $10000$, $10201$, $12100$ and $22201$, not one of them obeying the exact condition. Trying with $1$, $2$ and $3$ and I end up with nothing. Does this question even have an answer?

In any order you put $0, 1, 2$ the sum of the digits will be $100+200=300$. So, thanks to the rules of divisibility by $3$ and $9$, we can conclude that such number is divisible by $3$ and not by $9$. So the number is not a perfect square because it is of the form $3m$ with $m$ not divisible by $3$.
